# Class Trait does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm encountering an issue while deploying my PHP application. When I perform autoload using Composer, I receive the following error message: "does not comply with PSR-4 autoloading standard. Skipping."

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

##### `HandleUploadImageTrait.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\Image;

trait HandleImageTrait
{
    protected $path = 'upload/users';

    public function veryfy($request)
    {
        return $request->has('image');
    }
```

##### `User.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\HandleImageTrait;
// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use HandleImageTrait;
```

And output:

```
Generating optimized autoload files

Class App\Traits\HandleImageTrait located in C:/xampp/htdocs/workspace/laravel/Giap/GD-shop/app\Traits\HandleUploadImageTrait.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

I've searched on Stack Overflow and documentation but haven't been able to resolve this issue. I'm hoping the community can provide assistance or suggest a solution. Thank you for reading and helping!

I have attempted the following steps to address the issue:

1. Checked and corrected the namespace and class name according to PSR-4 standards.
2. Verified and updated the autoloader path in my composer.json file.
3. Executed the `composer dump-autoload` command to refresh the autoload.

I expected that these actions would resolve the PSR-4 autoloading error and allow for successful deployment of my PHP application. However, the issue persists, and I'm seeking guidance on any potential solutions or additional troubleshooting steps.

Comment: File `HandleUploadImageTrait.php` contains trait `HandleImageTrait`.